# How to start up a QA consulting business?

Tags: qa-role

I am considering to try out starting up/building a Software QA freelancing/consulting type of business. I have some skills in automation, and know at least java/javascript language. I just don't know how to maybe market my skills to build up my own business as a software QA. Any advice on this? Thanks :)

Here are some details on my situation based on the comments/answers posted on my original question:

1. My Location

I am physically located in the US, in the south, where IT is not really that I could say, popular? I am very new in the US coming from Asia

2. Why Hire Me?

I have the skill that a lot of IT companies wants to have in a QA and also the experience

3. What makes my service valuable?

The cost

4. What is my education background?

Bachelor's degree in Computer Science

5. What commercial QA software I or my company own?

No commercial QA software. I am more into Open source.

6.Would I bring my own hardware or be accessing the client's hardware?

I can do both

7. Have you thought about branding and a website?

Yes I have HTML/CSS/Javascript knowledge but website design is my weakness and, marketing

Comment: Not possible to answer, because it depends on OP's individual circumstances. In general, best way to start consulting business is to have plenty of experience and lots of contacts in industry (lot of people aware and valuing your skills), which you can gain after long productive career. Your name is your brand - how many people know you? Also, advice is so local that you might be better off asking on your local LinkedIn group. But without a name recognition, you compete by charging lower rate - a lose/lose proposition.

Comment: "What makes my service valuable? = The cost" ??? That's all? It's going to be hard for someone in the US to compete solely on cost.

Comment: Have you consulted through an Agency before? If not, you should. Then you could learn about being a consultant, and learn something about the business of owning a consultancy.

Comment: You might consider asking over here: http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not apply to software testing. This would be more appropriate on http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. yes @DEnumber50 this question can be closed. I asked someone from the startup stackexchange and they referred me to here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just some random thoughts:

- Check websites or brochures of small or medium sized companies for dead links, spelling or missing imprints.
- Download their demo software and try to break it in every possible way
- Send them your analysis results for free and mention that you are looking for consulting work

The bottom line is that you can prove upfront that you can add value to their business